# Change view with xib

Tags: iphone

I have one xib in portrait view and one in landscape view. I am changing xib in rotation like this:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_landscape", NSStringFromClass([self class])]
  owner: self
  options: nil];
```

It's working fine but if I open one view as a subview in the current view then it disappears. For example, on any button click I am adding one view (like a popover) in the current view, but in the rotation subview it disappears. How can I solve this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i suppose u r not adding the view on rotation that means as u said u have two different views for rotation so if u add any other view as subview u have to add the view twice one for landscape and one for potrait.r u doing so ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make property for that view and when ever you perform rotation you need to re add same view on the top of rest of the views by simply use `addSubview` function of `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing views for different mode,use autoresizing.It will let you work on single view autoResize when rotate.Here is fine example you can learn.

[AutoResizing](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_5_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a good approach. You should take one `UIViewController` with `XIB`. Now take two views(one for landscape and another for portrait connect it with `outlets`) outside `ViewController`'s view, and on at rotation time

```
yourCurrentView = landscapeView/portraitView;
 [self.view addSubview:yourCurrentView];
```

and set it `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:yourCurrentView];` //because what ever view added dynamically on self.view remains on top, now your view which was added always show at every mode.

I hope it will help you.